# dockerize a Rails app, error Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to dockerize a Rails app. The problem I get is that I get this error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The docker container that holds the Postgres(running btw):

```
3e11664277b3        postgres:9.6.1      "/docker-entrypoint.s"   2 days ago          Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:15432->5432/tcp                    mystore_prod_db_1
```

is containing the following databases:

```
 Name        |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 myshop_prod_db    | shopradu | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 myshop_production | shopradu | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 postgres          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 shopradu          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(6 rows)
```

I can connect mannually with user shopradu with the following command:

```
psql -d myshop_production -U shopradu
```

my .env.prod file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=shopradu
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somePassword
POSTGRES_HOST=prod_db
RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
SECRET_KEY_BASE=someKeyBase
```

the database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  username: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_PASSWORD"] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  username: radu
  password: devPassword
  database: mystore_dev

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV["POSTGRES_HOST"] %>
  database: myshop_production
```

The docker-compose.prod.yml file:

```
version: "2"

volumes:
  assets:
    external: false
  configs:
    external: false
  db-data:
    external: false

services:
  webserver:
    image: "nginx:1.11.8"
    env_file: .env.prod
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - assets:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - configs:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  prod_db:    
    image: postgres:9.6.1
    ports:
    - "15432:5432"
    env_file: .env.prod
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  prod_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    env_file: .env.prod
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - assets:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - configs:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - prod_db
- webserver
```

The Docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.5

RUN apt-get update -yqq \
  && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-client \
    nodejs \
  && apt-get -q clean


# Pre-install gems with native extensions
RUN gem install nokogiri -v "1.6.8.1"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .

# Pre-compile assets
ENV RAILS_ENV production
RUN rake assets:precompile

CMD script/start
```

Production.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or NGINX will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = !!ENV["RAILS_FORCE_SSL"].presence

  # Decrease the log volume.
  # config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

What can be here wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: db container's public port is not the default one: `- "15432:5432"`, so you have to specify it in rails databse.yml file.

Comment: connecting with psql without mentioning host connects via Unix socket. this is the different permission.

Comment: The sintax of specifying the port is    port: 15432:5432     ?   If I don't specify in docker.compose.prod.yml the port, this would mean that I should not modify the database.yml file with the port?

Comment: I think you have to use a links between your db and your RAILS app.

Answer (score 0):

In `docker-compose.yml`, you need to add a link between `prod_app` and `prod_db`. Excluding the current configuration, this is what is missing:

```
prod_app:
  links:
    - prod_db
```

What this does is add `prod_db` to `/etc/hosts` inside the `prod_app` image, which means you an use `prod_db` as the value for `POSTGRES_HOST`.

You don't need to change the port in `database.yml` by the way. The `ports` directive in `docker-compose.yml` maps a port on the host to a port on the container. The syntax is `HOST:CONTAINER`, meaning `15672:5672` maps port 15672 on the host (i.e. your machine) to port 5672 on the container. It is necessary only if you want to connect to a container from the host. Containers don't need this port mapping to communicate between each other. As soon as you link two containers, they can communicate on all their ports with each other.

Comment: It is still not working. When I try to connect mannually to the database as 
 shopradu user    psql -h prod_db -p 5432 -U shopradu -W  somePassword myshop_production    >>> it asks for the password, i provide the one in the .env.prod somePassword. than I get the error psql: invalid port number: " 5432"   I made sure that the user shopradu has the password provided in the .env.prod file, using the ALTER USER shopradu WITH PASSWORD 'somePassword'; from the postgres console.